# React this.props is undefined though props is passed in constructor and super

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to access `this.props`, but it is undefined

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props) <-- undefined
    this.state = {
        req: {
            userId: 1,
            skip: 0,
            limit: 10
        },
        posts: []
    }
}
```

Accessing this component from **App.tsx** through

```html
<Route path='/posts/:userId' component={() => <Posts />} />
```

I am trying to access **userId** through `this.props.match.params`. I should be able to console **this.props**, but somehow it is undefined.

Comment: Can you share the code of the parent component?

Comment: try `console.log(props)` instead.

Comment: @Emanuele This code itself is in the container. So, parent component for this would be **App.tsx**

Comment: @SultanH. I tried that too. No luck. Still undefined.

Comment: From where you are calling this component, post your parent component.

Comment: Shashwat if this is the container, why would you expect to receive any props in here? are you actually sending any props from **App.tsx**?

Comment: @rdarioduarte Actually, I am trying to access **this.props.match.params**

Comment: In that case you should update the question with complete information, because we don't know what you are trying to access and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Route` is incorrect,

```
<Route path='/posts/:userId' component={() => <Posts />} />
```

You should either do this,

```
<Route path='/posts/:userId' render={(props) => <Posts {...props} />} />
```

or

```
<Route path='/posts/:userId' component={(props) => <Posts {...props} />} />
```

or

```
<Route path='/posts/:userId' component={Posts} />
```

And finally you can access your `props` in component like,

```
{props.match.params.userId} //for functional component
{this.props.match.params.userId} //for class based component
```

For more [info](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props).

Answer (score 0):

Is your class extending the `React.Component` class?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is extending React.Component

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor the param passed to your instance is `props`.
`this.props` that you are trying to access is the props of your class and not the props passed to your constructor.

If you want to display the `props` passed by default to your component, you should log `console.log(props)` because `this.props` is not defined yet.

If you want to display your props after creating your components (if for example your component is being rendered multiple times because of an async call by the parent) you should maybe put your console.log in the `render` method

Comment: I tried to console **props** as well, but no success.

Comment: It's normal, it's your constructor, and depends on the parent component, you may have nothing.

Can your class, how do you call your component and the props passed to your component `<MyComponent name='x' value='y' />`

Comment: in your render method, if you put the console.log, is it still undefined ?

Comment: `<Route path='/posts/:userId' component={() => <Posts />} />`
So, I am trying to access userId though `this.props.match.params`

Comment: You cannot access it, it is different here.

You should Wrap your component with `WithRouter`.
`Import withRouter from "react-router-dom/withRouter`

and in your component `export class withRouter(MyComponent)`

Like that you will have access to router props.